# Least Common Multiple Notation

Tags: notation, least-common-multiple

I was looking at the Wikipedia page on [Coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) when I found this:

If an integer ${\displaystyle c|{\textrm {lcm}}(a,b)} $ and $ {\displaystyle \gcd(a,b,c)=1} $ ,  then $ {\displaystyle g(a,b,c)={\textrm {lcm}}(c,a)+{\textrm {lcm}}(c,b)-a-b-c}.$

What is ${\displaystyle c|{\textrm {lcm}}(a,b)}$? I used Google and Wikipedia, but I still can't find what it means. I even searched here.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain words:

> $c$ divides the lowest common multiple of $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `|` means "divides", `lcm` means "least common mutliple", `gcd` means "greatest common divisor", and `g` denotes the Frobenius number.